# How to make an image fade to another image when a certain amount of light falls on a LDR?

Tags: image, processing

I have been trying to make an image transistion to another image when a certain amount of light falls on a LDR, and transistions back when that light is not shining on the LDR anymore. However, the piece of code is not working properly. I am new to processing, so there is a good chance that I am doing it completely wrong. It would be lovely if someone could help me achieve the fade in and out! Thanks in advance! Here is a part of my code, and what I have tried to do for the fade:
 `

```
int transparency = 0;

void setup() {
  img = loadImage(imgFileName+"."+fileType);
  bla = loadImage("mermaid.jpg");
  size(img.width, img.height);
  image(img, 0, 0);

  println(Arduino.list());
  arduino = new Arduino(this, Arduino.list()[0], 57600);
  arduino.pinMode(ledPin, Arduino.OUTPUT);
  arduino.pinMode(sensorPin, Arduino.INPUT);
}
void draw() {
      int analogValue =  arduino.analogRead(sensorPin);
      println(analogValue);

      if (analogValue > 900) {
        noTint();
        image(bla, 0, 0);
      } else {
        while (column < width-1) {
          img.loadPixels(); 
          sortColumn();
          column++;
          img.updatePixels();
        }

        while (row < height-1) {
          img.loadPixels(); 
          sortRow();
          row++;
          img.updatePixels();
        }

     if (transparency < 255) {
          transparency++; 
        }
        tint(255, 255, 255, transparency);
        image(img, 0, 0);
        //automatically save the image 
        if (!saved && frameCount >= loops) {
          saveFrame(imgFileName+"_"+mode+".png");
          saved = true;
        }
      }
    }`
```

Comment: Break your problem down into smaller steps. Can you create a simple sketch that just fades between two pictures without any sensor? Then can you create another simple sketch that simply prints out whether light is shining on it or not? If you get stuck on one of those specific steps, then you'll be able to ask a more specific question. It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. It's easier to answer "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead. What's going on?" type questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am able to do both, so I will think how to make my question more specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach seems to be more complicated than necessary, as it a fade transition can be handled solely by the tint function without reloading all of the pixels in an image. Additionally, transparency doesn't decrease at any point in the sketch. A simple alternative might be:

```
void draw() {
  int analogValue =  arduino.analogRead(sensorPin);
  println(analogValue);
  noTint();
  image(bla, 0, 0);
  if (analogValue > 900) {
    if (transparency > 0) {
      transparency--;
    }
  } else {
    if (transparency < 255) {
      transparency++; 
    }
  }
  tint(255, transparency);
  //only need 1 color variable, ref. https://processing.org/reference/fill_.html
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```